# Map of textual locations, rather than coordinates ,with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I know how to pass coordinates to Google Maps like so:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];
```

I'm interested to know if you have to have coordinates. I have a website with hundereds of users who have entered their own citys. Can I map these users without running a script to generate coordinates for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of mapping placenames to coordinates is called Geocoding. There is a [Google Geocoding API available](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). You could also call this API on the fly for your city names to get the coordinates - or you run a background script to find all geocoordinates for your cities at once. Both options are possible with almost no changes to the rest of your mapping code.

Answer (score 1):

The map only works with latitude and longitude to set a center or makers, but you can use the [**geocoding service**](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) to convert place names, and eventually save the coordinates. [**Docs here.**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Geocoder)